# Error with sysprep in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, sysprep

I have a recurring problem using `Sysprep` on our Windows 10 machines. I use `Sysprep` with an answer file. When I send our windows image on machines with almost the same hardware, everything works perfectly.

However, lets say my source machine is a ASUS and I decide to `Sysprep` my Windows 10 installation and send it to a HP machine, I get this message:

> The Computer Restarted unexpectedly or encountered an unexpected error

after System Startup.

Normally, I can open `regedit` using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and change the child completion parameter to 3 instead of 1 and it works but I want to understand and fix this error. I never found any reason why I get this error and how to fix it permanently...

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Please don't [cross post](http://serverfault.com/questions/815040/error-during-sysprep); pick a site and post it there. If you decide you want it moved, flag your existing one and request a moderator migrate it.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours I found the solution. `SYSPREP` in Windows 10 doesn't like any settings in the specialize phase of the unattended.xml file.

As long as I put nothing in this phase, it works. I transferred the settings declared there to the OOBE system.